# Why did The Ripper kill this Hexenbiest?

Tags: grimm

On the Season 4 Episode 21 of Grimm:

> We see the possessed Sean Renard continue killing  Portland's ladies of the night. But in that same episode, we see him kill Henrietta. Why did Renard-the-Ripper kill Henrietta? She didn't seem to be any threat to him, as she claimed to not have any knowledge of what ailed him. Furthermore, Henrietta was hailed as an all-powerful, all-knowing Hexenbiest; how did Renard kill her so easily? She should have seen him coming from a mile away.

[image]

Comment: He killed her because Ripper preys on Wesen. She was probably not on guard because she knew Renard.

Comment: But, so far he's only preyed on Wesen hookers. She was not a hooker. Why do something so uncharacteristic? Just seems like a giant plot hole.

Comment: Perhaps she died of shame from being in the same episode as his "British" accent.

Answer (score 2):

#### We could call it any number of things, a humbug, a plot hole, a contrivance but mostly what we should call it is convenience and poor quality writing.

- Given the fact we are told that Henrietta is supposedly a super-private, very powerful and formidable Hexenbiest, her apparent demise not only stings but rings very false to the viewers who know just what a powerful Hexenbiest can do.
- Perhaps Jack knew or suspected what Reynard was up to, given some time, a Hexenbiest of Henrietta's skill could conceivably come up with a plan to deal with spiritual possession. The Spice Shop Crew and Adelaid did.

**Or perhaps the answer lies behind the fourth wall. In the online magazine, [The Wrap - November 14, 2014](http://www.thewrap.com/white-house-downs-garcelle-beauvais-books-recurring-role-on-grimm-exclusive/) we learn:**

- **Garcelle Beauvais** (the actress who plays Henrietta) has landed a monstrous new gig. The talented actress has joined NBC’s “Grimm” in a recurring role, The Wrap has learned.
- Beauvais will play Henrietta — a Hexenbiest who is a longtime family friend of Captain Renard (Sasha Roiz). He seeks out her guidance and wisdom after a surprising development occurs with someone in the Grimm gang.
- Currently, she’s booked for **three episodes** beginning with Episode 411, with the **possibility** of more.
- **She appeared in four shows**: "Death Do Us Part", "Maréchaussée", "Bad Luck", and "You Don't Know Jack", thus likely fulfilling her contractual obligations.

**I would like to think there would have been a better, more fitting ending for the character as they established her; alas the viewer doesn't always get what they want or deserve... perhaps they were over-budget or had some other extenuating circumstance we aren't privy to as to why her death was so sudden and without excess incident.**